# Is there any C# command to remove the ".." in a path?

Tags: c#, file-io

I have the following:

```
// Get my executable's path
string exeFile = ( new System.Uri( Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase ) ).AbsolutePath;

// Get its directory
string exeFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName( exeFile );

// Get rid of those %20 and stuff
exeFolder = Uri.UnescapeDataString( exeFolder );

// Get some relative path from my .config file
string relativePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyRelativePath"] );

// Woa. The final result, uff.
string myFinalPath = Path.Combine( exeFolder, relativePath );
```

Now, if MyRelativePath is something like `..\Xpto\PleaseReadMe.txt` and my executable is located in `C:\Ypto\RunMe.exe`, I will end with:

`C:\Ypto\..\Xpto\PleaseReadMe.txt`

instead of

`C:\Xpto\PleaseReadeMe.txt`

Considering that I must present this path in a textbox, of course I don't want users to see the ugly "\Ypto.." part. I can easily make a function with a few lines to parse this string and remove these constructions, but I wonder if there is a C# method that elegantly does this. If not, what algorithm do you recommend?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `Path.GetFullPath()`.

Comment: It will not work as expected, I had already tried it. Let me explain. The code I presented is in a Windows Form application. I have a .bat that do some stuff (e.g. .NET 4.0 is not present? Then install it first.) before running the .exe.

Well, that batch is in a root folder, say, C:\AAA. The .exe is in a bin folder in C:\AAA\bin. If I use Path.GetFullPath() when calling the .exe from the .bat, it will use the .bat's location as reference, instead of the .exe one. If I run directly the .exe by entering in the bin folder, then it works.

Comment: @RuiMiguelPinheiro you need to put all this in the problem statment if it is relevant to finding an answer.

Comment: SLaks, I'm so sorry. I was revising diffs between my commit with the GetFullPath tentative to better answer Rubens Farias with a real test case. Then I noticed a flaw in the usage of GetFullPath. I reverted the code and removed the flaw - now GetFullPath is working as expected. The answer is correct. Because your timestamp is 1 minute earlier, you will get the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with [`Path.GetFullPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) method. Also, you can remove the `Uri` handling:

```
// Get my executable's path
string exeFile = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;

// Get its directory
string exeFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName( exeFile );

// Get some relative path from my .config file
string relativePath = @"..\Xpto\PleaseReadMe.txt";

// Woa. The final result, uff.
string myFinalPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(exeFolder, relativePath));

Console.WriteLine(myFinalPath);
```

Sample test:

- C:\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\SAMPLE.CMD
  `@DEBUG\ConsoleApplication1.exe`

Output:

`C:\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Xpto\PleaseReadMe.txt`

Comment: I already commented on SLaks answer why GetFullPath won't work with my use case. Not sure about removing the Uri handling. If I don't use it, I will end with %20 if the path has spaces on it.

Comment: Can you provide a real test case?

Comment: Rubens Farias, please read my last comment to SLaks. Both you were rights, it was just me that did crap in the code :(